# Redirect URL in Salesforce1

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app, mobile, mobilesdk

How can I pass parameters to a page using Salesforce1?

In classic vforce, I use a controller that modifies the page ref but sends parameters.  Can I do a simliar process using NavigateToURL(ref, [isRedirect]);

```
public PageReference redirect() {
    map<string, string> params = apexpages.currentPage().getparameters();
    params.put('Name', 'Testname');
    System.PageReference p = new System.PageReference('/a05/e');
    p.getParameters().putAll(params);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Is this a custom page or standard ?

Comment: In the case above its standard.  Does it make a difference?

Comment: Yes because url hacking doesn't work on standard page in SF1.

Comment: I'll look at my project on Monday and see if it applies